# Azure Mobile Service for Windows Phone 8.1 - Insert to existing DB

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

I am writing an app that has an Azure database. I've never did nything connected with Azure, so I am new to all the stuff. I've found on the internet and at microsoft documentation some tutorials, but I must have got sth wrong, cause it doesn't work. So I have a table at my database called Week, I've created a model in my code:

```
[DataContract]
public class Week
{
    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    //[DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Book")]
    [DataMember]
    public Book CurrentBook { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Is_Read")]
    [DataMember]
    public Boolean IsRead { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Pages_Read")]
    [DataMember]
    public int PagesRead { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Start_Date")]
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "User")]
    [DataMember]
    public User Reader { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Week_Number")]
    [DataMember]
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }

    public Week(Book currentBook, Boolean isRead, int pagesRead, DateTime startDate, User reader, int weekNumber)
    {
        CurrentBook = currentBook;
        IsRead = isRead;
        PagesRead = pagesRead;
        StartDate = startDate;
        Reader = reader;
        WeekNumber = weekNumber;
    }

    public Week()
    {

    }

    public int GetMonth()
    {
        //TODO: Implement the method.
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then I created the WeekRepository for CRUD operations:

```
public class WeekRepository : BaseRepository<Week>
{
    private IMobileServiceTable<Week> weekTable;

    public string errorMesage = string.Empty;

    public WeekRepository()
    {
        weekTable = MobileService.GetTable<Week>();
    }


    public async override Task<int> Save(Week entity)
    {
        try
        {
            await weekTable.InsertAsync(entity);
            //    .ContinueWith(t =>
            //{
            //    if (t.IsFaulted)
            //    {
            //        errorMesage = "Insert failed";
            //    }
            //    else
            //    {
            //        errorMesage = "Inserted a new item with id " + entity.Id;                       
            //    }
            //});
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            errorMesage = ex.Message;
        }
        return entity.Id;
    }

    public override void Update(Week entity)
    {
        return;
    }

    public override Week Load(int bookId)
    {
        var week = weekTable.Where(w => w.IsRead == false).ToListAsync();
        return week.Result.Single();
    }

    public override List<Week> LoadByUserId(int userId)
    {
        return new List<Week>();
    }

    public Week LoadCurrentWeek(int userId)
    {
        return new Week();
    }
}
```

To test if it works, I wrote a simple test:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldSaveWeekToTheDB()
    {
        //ARANGE
        Week weekTestEntity = new Week(null, false, 10, new DateTime(), null, 1);

        //ACT
        int id = weekRepository.Save(weekTestEntity).Result;

        //ASSERT
        var savedItem = weekRepository.Load(1);
        Assert.AreEqual(false, savedItem.IsRead);
    }
```

However, InsertAsync() throws an exception - Not Found. I've no idea what I am doing wrong, cause it seems a simple thing as far as I can see from the material on the Internet.

If You could help me, I would be really grateful!
Thank You in advance!

Best Regards,
Roman.

Comment: Any luck on this? Ive been having the same issues. No solid documentation out there outlining how to connect windows phone to azure database (besides a useless Todo app). Everything out there is either out of date or not specific enough.

Comment: As far as I remember it was something with the publish file. I'll check when I come home.